# transfer mysql query to php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that runs directly on phpmyadmin> SQL query used to reset the password for the user. I use password variable and id variable to implement sql query

```
UPDATE xf_user_authenticate
SET data = BINARY
CONCAT(
CONCAT(
CONCAT('a:3:{s:4:"hash";s:40:"', SHA1(CONCAT(SHA1('password'), SHA1('salt')))),
CONCAT('";s:4:"salt";s:40:"', SHA1('salt'))
),
'";s:8:"hashFunc";s:4:"sha1";}'
),
scheme_class = 'XenForo_Authentication_Core'
WHERE user_id = myid;
```

But i can't transfer the above code into php to execute the query

```
  $sql2="query";

  // id = $row['user_id']
  // user = $username

  $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
  $stmt2->execute();
  $row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: `But i can't transfer the above code into php to execute the query` <- why not? What's wrong? What errors get displayed?

Comment: yes, i have problems with strings

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php on escaping quotes.

Comment: @LongKien what problem with strings?

Comment: $sql2="UPDATE xf_user_authenticate
      SET data = BINARY
      CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
      CONCAT('a:3:{s:4:"hash";s:40:"', SHA1(CONCAT(SHA1('123456'), SHA1('salt')))),
      CONCAT('";s:4:"salt";s:40:"', SHA1('salt'))
      ),
      '";s:8:"hashFunc";s:4:"sha1";}'
      ),
      scheme_class = 'XenForo_Authentication_Core'
      WHERE user_id = 1;";

Comment: phpmyadmin has a button that will export your query directly to php

Comment: I tried the same thing but couldn't $sql2="UPDATE xf_user_authenticate SET data = BINARY CONCAT( CONCAT( CONCAT('a:3:{s:4:"hash";s:40:"', SHA1(CONCAT(SHA1('123456'), SHA1('salt')))), CONCAT('";s:4:"salt";s:40:"', SHA1('salt')) ), '";s:8:"hashFunc";s:4:"sha1";}' ), scheme_class = 'XenForo_Authentication_Core' WHERE user_id = 1";

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai meh, might as well learn to code it though instead of relying on third-party softwares ^^

Comment: @LongKien read into PDO and how to use that lib, then everything should hopefully fall into place

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you say. But the problem I'm having with the chain transfer and the trouble surrounding it. I have tried many ways and headaches about it, looking forward to more specific advice from you